# Running irb in emacs (via run-ruby) echos everything I type

Tags: ruby, emacs

I'm running Windows Vista and Emacs 23.1.1 and I have installed Ruby using the "One Click Ruby Installer".  I then installed the Emacs Lisp files that were installed with Ruby as specified in inf-ruby.el.

When I run the run-ruby (M-x run-ruby) function, irb starts but every time I press Enter, irb prints out the line I just typed.  For example:

```
irb(main):001:0> def foo()
def foo()
                   3 + 4
3 + 4
                 end
end
nil
```

This is annoying.  If I just run irb in a cygwin command shell, no echoing is performed.  For example:

```
$ irb.bat --inf-ruby-mode
irb(main):001:0> def foo()
                   3 + 4
                   end
nil
```

How do I turn off the echoing in Emacs?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inferior Ruby mode is built on top of comint-mode.

I noticed that there was a comint variable named comint-process-echoes.

I set this variable to t (true) and the echoing stopped.

Here's how I set the variable:

```
;;; Define Ruby Mode Hook
(defun my-ruby-mode-hook ()
  (progn
    (setq comint-process-echoes t)
    (turn-on-font-lock)
    (auto-fill-mode)
    (yas/minor-mode)
    (inf-ruby-keys)))

;;; Register Ruby Mode Hook
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook 'my-ruby-mode-hook)
```

Comment: FYI you don't need the progn

Comment: I don't think the answer needs all the unrelated customizations not soving the problem of OP (like YASnippet etc.)

Answer (score 3):

should be this:

> (defun echo-false ()
>   (setq comint-process-echoes t))
>
> (add-hook 'comint-mode-hook 'echo-false)